# Android slider to select

Tags: android, android-widget

I am wondering about the best way to approach this problem...

I have a game, and the way the user will select which team they are on, is to slide their chosen character to the left or the right, (two teams to choose from).

Would it be best to create my own view that does this, or is there an android interface available that would work?

My initial thoughts were to use the SeekBar, as with 3 values it has the correct feel (i.e. it locks onto the left or the right with a finger swipe), but I don't want to have the progress bar underlay. I'm not sure if I can completely change the look of this either, so I think I need to try something else.

Comment: You should be able to apply your own theme and drawables to the `SeekBar` and customize it to suit your needs.